# How to create a flexible menu ? Is there any API?

Tags: java, user-interface

I need to create a GUI that would have a list of items. User should be able to `add new item` and `edit description` for each item. After the application is closed the information should be stored in the root.

I know how to make this list of items but I do not know how I can allow user to add new items. Can anybody give me a code example ?

Especially, I need to know how I can make this `add new item` work.

Comment: you might want to use window builder. also simply keep the items in a file and read them to the list ..

Answer (score 3):

This is a broad question, but using swing you could create a `JList` with your objects contained in them. For the button `add new btn` you would attach an `ActionListener` that would essentially have it create a new object and make sure you add this object to the `JList`.

After this set up some behaviors that would allow you to click on the object in list view which would transition/open new swing JPanel which would have a editable textview for your description.

Commit all these changes into a database.

Of course it is easier said than done. Read up on java swing gui implementation.

Here are some resources [1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/) [2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/)

Edit: changed listview to jlist (been working with android lately)

Comment: +1 for answer . However very vague. everybody knows this links .

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in a million different ways. If you can make use of Angular, here's an example

HTML markup for the dropdown menu

```
<li class="dropdown" ng-controller="DropdownCtrl">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle">
    Click me for a dropdown, yo!
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
      <a>{{choice}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

Setting up the initial values for the dropdown. Typically, you would be retrieving this from the Backend application with an ajax/rest call.

```
function DropdownCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.items = [
    "The first choice!",
    "And another choice for you.",
    "but wait! A third!"
  ];
 $scope.newItem={};
    }
```

Next step is to create a form to let users add to the menus. Some like..

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="Controller">
      <form novalidate class="simple-form">
        Name: <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.name" /><br />
        Description: <textarea  ng-model="newItem.description"></textarea><br />

        <button ng-click="reset()">RESET</button>
        <button ng-click="addToDropdown()">SAVE</button>
      </form>
      <pre>form = {{user | json}}</pre>
      <pre>master = {{master | json}}</pre>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and then, write a controller to add it to the existing item list and also send the updates to the backend. Something like this

```
    function Controller($scope) {

function addToDropdown(){
   $scope.items.push(angular.copy(newItem));
   $scope.newItem={};
}
    }
```

You can post this data back to the backend using [$http service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24http#methods_post) or angular or a module called Restangular.

This is a basic guide to get started. Hope it helps.

Comment: +1 for answer. However, the question is about java not html or javascript